# Uploading files from POST data

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a page that allows users to upload images to a directory. The upload segment of the page looks like this:

```
<form action="resources/includes/uploaded.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="text" name="description">
    <button class="newimage" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

with my PHP function looking like this:

```
    $_SESSION['random'] = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,15);
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        }
      else
        {

        if (file_exists("../../uploads/" . $_SESSION['random']))
          {
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "../../uploads/" . $_SESSION['random']);

          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }

      ...DATABASE QUERIES ETC.
```

The above results in "Invalid image" being printed when images that are within the set restrictions are uploaded. I'm unsure as to what the issue is as the file is there, it's correctly named and referenced in the function - any ideas?

Comment: have you checked if it is being saved? have you printed the contents of `$_FILE` and checked that it matches what you expect?

Comment: First of all, don't rely on the "type" to ensure that it's an image: this is sent by the client and can easily be faked. To debug your issue, use `echo` or `var_dump` to see what values you are working with, and from there it should be easy to see which condition is failing. From your code, I can't even tell which condition the "Invalid file" block is an `else` for: the formatting is very hard to follow.

Comment: add `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); echo "</pre">` and check the result - does all the data really match? It doesn't! Otherwhise your script would NOT go into the "else" part of your first check!

Comment: have you checked the uploaded file size is less than 200000000?

Comment: don't rely on extensions.

Comment: I thought part of the issue might be using `==` for comparing strings, but I just tested it out and it seems to work. As a general rule, `strcmp` or `strcasecmp` are generally safer than `==`.

Comment: the allowed extensions array does not have pjpg,x-png formats.. and don't validate based on file extensions

Comment: @Amith it also does not contain "PNG, JPG, JPEG" - what is the most common used Extension. (Note the Upper Case)

Comment: yes the file extensions are case sensitive in linux and not in windows.. so based on your server environment you should check file extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be improved in many ways. You're currently checking the file type based on the image's mime-types. Checking if an input file matches the mime type doesn't really prevent anything. It can easily be spoofed and `$_FILES['file']['mime-type']` **shouldn't ever be trusted**. They are only meant to be used as hints, and should not be used for validating user uploads.

Coming to the problems in your code, you're currently comparing the image mime-types with a predefined set of mime types. I'd remove that conditional statement, and use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) instead:

```
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['name']);
$mime_type = $image['mime'];
```

Also, you're currently using `explode()` to extract the filename:

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
```

This is fine, and would work as you expected. But you could use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) function instead, which is specifically designed for this purpose.

```
$path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Here's the improved version if your code (untested):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$imagesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"]; //storing size into a variable

$path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$image = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['name']);
$mime_type = $image['mime'];

if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && $size < 200000000) 
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0) //0 means no errors
    {
        if (!file_exists("../../uploads/" . $_SESSION['random']))  
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "../../uploads/" . $_SESSION['random']);
        }
    }    
}

else
{
    echo "File validation failed.";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Was going to write this as a comment, but went way too long:

Debugging Step 1

First try breaking up all of your conditions into separate if statements so that it returns whether it's passing or failing those conditions.. so if you have `if ( ( A || B || C ) && D && E)` then write out** `if (A) { echo "A is true" } else { "A is false" }` for A through E, and then see if your truth values are what you expect them to be.

If your values aren't what you expect them to be, then your condition is wrong.

If your values are what you expect them to be, then your logic is wrong.

Let us know which is the case, and we can help you more effectively :)

**Also, instead of writing out `if (A) { echo "A is true" } else { "A is false" }` for A through E, you could use the following:

```
function check($letter, $condition)
{
    $retval = ($condition) ? "True" : "False";
    echo $letter." is ".$retval;
}

check( ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") );
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="file"  name="img" />
```

**PHP**

```
$_width = 125;
$_height = 150;
$imageData = @getimagesize($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);

if((($_FILES["img"]["type"] != "image/jpeg")&& ($_FILES["img"]["type"] != "image/png")&& ($_FILES["img"]["type"] != "image/jpg") && ($_FILES["img"]["size"] > 50000) && (($imageData[0] != $_width) && ($imageData[1] != $_height) )   ){
echo "validation not met";
}
```